# How can I use this function in multiprocessing?

Tags: python, function, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I want to apply this function in multiprocessing:

```
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(1,4, size=(10,10,10))

def function(input_field,[num1,num2,num3]):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    test_list = [(a,[27.5, 27.5, 25]), (b,[27.5, 27.5, 25]), (c,[27.5, 27.5, 25]), (d,[27.5, 27.5, 25])]
    results = pool.map(function, test_list)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

How can I apply `function(input_field,[num1,num2,num3])` to multiprocessing?

Comment: that's `function(input_field,[num1,num2,num3])` a syntax error. Just change the function to recieve 1 argument which is the tuples from the list, and then unpack it inside the function or change `map` to `starmap`

Comment: the list `[27.5, 27.5, 25]` is the same for all items, is that intentionally?

Comment: starmap is simple solution to me. @RomanPerekhrest yes, it wrote the list intentionally.

Comment: @Newbie0105, I didn't tell you about starmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options based on the structure of your `test_list`:

1. modify your function to support a single argument and unpack it inside the function and keep using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map):

   ```
   def function(arg):
       input_field, l = arg
   ```
2. use [`starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap) and fix your function definition, because the structure of `test_list` is what `starmap` is expecting to get:

   ```
   def function(input_field, l):
   ...
   results = pool.starmap(function, test_list)
   ```

Comment: I mean, your comment about my code worked. I just changed from "map" to "starmap" and it worked. Thanks a lot!